# NetCDF: Attribute not found error when using name with undescore

Tags: netcdf4

My app is using netCDF4 to read the header of the file. The error occurs when reading one the attributes defined with a name containing an underscore. The snippet reads:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
...
        self.dataset = nc.Dataset(out_file)
        self.tempus.start_date = self.dataset.START_DATE
        self.tempus.e_we = self.dataset.WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION
```

This reads the start date without any problem but it crashes when it tries to read WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION with `AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found`. Further details include:

```
File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4/pyx", line 3120, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__getattr__
File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4/pyx", line 3065, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.getncattr
File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4/pyx", line 1530, in netCDF4._netCDF4.__get_att
File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4/pyx", line 2014, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
```

I've run into this issue a few times and it always happens when the name uses an underscore.